# Finding exact hsv values for colors with green and purple in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am tring to detect the plant with the colors of green and purple using opencv color detection. I have done it for the green color, but I am unable to get the exact lower range and upper range of the color green + purple. The values I have used would detect all the colors in the image. Values:

```
lower_purple = np.array([[80, 10, 10]])
upper_purple = np.array([120, 255, 255])
```

How can I get the exact hsv range of the values for each color.

Comment: For the color, go to [this website](http://colorizer.org/), for the opencv conversion [look at the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html). I am pretty sure this _type_ of color conversion question has several answers on StackOverflow!

Comment: magenta has H = 150, green has H = 60. set your bounds around these two intervals. green + purple isn't a color.